# Why getClass returns the name of the class + $1 (or $*)

Tags: java, instanceof

I'm writing a piece of code in which I have to cast an Object if it is an instance of a certain class.

As usual I'm using `instanceof` for checking the compatibility.

The problem is that the check is never satisfied because the objects belong to "strange" classes.

For example; when I call the method `getClass().getSimpleName()` on this object it return me the name of the class + `$*` (e.g. `ViewPart$1` instead of `ViewPart`).

What does this `$*` means?
Is there a solution or a workaround?

Comment: is that an anonynous inner class?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That shows an *inner class* (either anonymous (if it has a number) or named). For example:

```
class Foo {
    static class Bar {
    }
}
```

The name of class `Foo.Bar` is `Foo$Bar`. Now if we had:

```
class Foo {

    static void bar() {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {};
        };

        System.out.println(r.getClass());
    }
}
```

That will print `Foo$1`.

You can see the same effect in the naming of the class files created by javac.

Answer (score 4):

These are instances of an [anonymous class](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm). `ViewPart$1` is the first anonymous class defined inside `ViewPart` - but that doesn't mean it's a subclass of `ViewPart`. It's most likely an anoymous implementation of some Listener interface.

Comment: Is it documented the fact that the `Class$X` points to the `X`th anonymous class?

Comment: @Hablutzel: no, the JLS only says the name should have the format, $ followed by digits. The sequence of digits is an implementation detail of the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

$ denotes for inner class. For example consider two classes

```
public class TopClass {
  class SubClass {
     // some methods
  }// inner class end
} // outer class end
```

If you compile this code you will get two class files TopClass.class and TopClass$SubClass.class.

Check your ViewPart class whether it has any inner classes.
Hope it helps.