# Class Name for Java anonymous class

Tags: java, methods, overriding, anonymous-inner-class

```
Class A{

 public void test(){
   B b = new B();
   System.out.println( "Class Name: " + b.createClassC().getClass() );
 }

}

Class B{
   public C createClassC(){
     C c = new C(){
       @Override
       public boolean equals( Object other ){
         return true;
       }    
     }; 
   }
}

Class C{
   int val = 8;
}
```

Output:
Class Name: *package.name.here*.B

Can some one tell me why anonymous class types gives the enclosing class in the getClass() method? This causes the .equals() on the object C to fail all the time. My understanding is since the getClass gives the enclosing class name, the overridden equals is never invoked?

Comment: That's **not** what it outputs. It outputs `package.name.here.B$1` The `$1` indicates it's an anonymous class. Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172581/why-getclass-returns-the-name-of-the-class-1-or

Comment: @jahroy It does as an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). The issue is that the supposed output isn't what is actually output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

output is `Class Name: class nz.test.anon.B$1` the dollar sign is important. B$1 means first anonymous class under B. B$2 is second and so on.

also the equals method is being called

```
System.out.println( "This is true: " + b.createClassC().equals(b) );
System.out.println( "and so is this: " + b.createClassC().equals(this) );
```

Comment: Do you know of an official reference that clearly states the naming of anonymous classes?

Answer (score 1):

No idea how you are running you code. Some points to note are as follows -

- First if all where is the main() method? How does your program start?
  There must be one

`public static void main(String args[])`

method in your project.

- Secondly see your method

  public C createClassC(){
       C c = new C(){
         @Override
         public boolean equals( Object other ){
           return true;
         }
       }; 
     }

Function signature dictates it should return an object of Class C(or it's subclass) but I see no such return statement. You must `return c;`

Finally the output of your code is `Class Name: class nz.test.anon.B$1` in which B$1 means an anonymous class.