# Creating a unique class at runtime for use as a key in a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, anonymous-class

I understand this is a terrible hack, but I'm required to edit an external library to conform to our project's needs.  The project I'm changing stores a map of classes to instances of said classes.  The project's original intention is to make it impossible to have duplicate classes, but I require them.  My solution is to apply a UniqueClass field to each relevant object, and then each object also have a reference to the class that I need to create an instance of.  In this way, what the UniqueClass is doesn't actually matter at all, only that it's unique.

Now, I need a way to create a unique class at runtime to store in this map.  Here are the options I see:

1. Generate and compile the actual .java files at runtime.  I've actually implemented this and it works, but it's somewhat slow and requires JDK (doesn't work with JRE since it needs access to certain libraries).  I don't want to require JDK configuration since non-devs will likely be using this functionality.
2. Generate a unique anonymous class.  This works, but only with the first duplicate.  Any additional duplicates are treated as the same as the original anonymous class (ClassBuilder$1).  I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264422/class-name-for-java-anonymous-class) it's possible to have ClassBuilder$2 etc, but I don't know how to do that.

   ```
    Object object = new Object(){};
    return object.getClass();
   ```
3. Use a Proxy class.  I don't really understand these but it had the same results as anonymous class above, since the javadocs state that if a proxy class already exists, it just returns that one.

   ```
   Class proxyClass = Proxy.getProxyClass(inter.class.getClassLoader(), new Class[] { inter.class });  
   return proxyClass;
   ```
4. (Truly the most terrible way) Create a package of classes that are iterated through as each one is used as a UniqueClass.  Ugly code, lots of unnecessary classes, and ultimately a limit on the number of duplicates possible.

Is there an elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: I'd suggest looking to override/extend the library if possible rather than "trick" it.  If you need to trick it, you might be able to use CGLib https://github.com/cglib/cglib/wiki/Tutorial.  Note that in java 7 and below classes are stored in permgen, creating these in an open ended fashion can lead to Permgen errors which will typically bring your app to a halt.

Comment: When you say _"edit an external library "_ do you mean you have access to the library's source code and can modify it? Or do you have to work wit only the .class files?

Comment: Does the Map in the library directly use `Class<?>` objects as keys? Does it wrap them in something else?  There's a lot of important context you need to share with us, or you risk turning this into an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: @JimGarrison I am modifying the source code itself.  I do not think there is a way to achieve what I want easily without doing so.  And yes, it uses Class<?> as key.

Comment: Can you explain more your second option ?

Comment: @CMPS The syntax I put there creates an anonymous class that extends from Object.  The hash for this newly created class is "ClassBuilder$1" (ClassBuilder is the class with the method that created the class).  This successfully is treated as a Class object, but if I do it again, it has the same hash as the original anonymous class (ClassBuilder$1).  I'd like to figure out how to create an anonymous class with $2, $3, etc, which will be treated differently by the map.

Comment: @MeowgooCat can you extend the type of the class from which the anonymous class inherit ?

Answer (score 0):

> I am modifying the source code itself.

In that case create a wrapper object to use as the key in the `Map`.  You can override `equals()` and `hashCode()` as necessary to achieve your goals.  In essence you are adding one more layer of indirection to your existing multi-map of classes and instances.

Comment: This was something I tried as well, but it didn't work because the library has more indirect dependencies on this map containing precisely classes.  Namely, it indirectly checks if the class exists in the map based on an separately-created instance class.  I can overwrite hashCode() to return the class and fix this problem, but then I'm back to where I started.

Comment: You may need to subclass the `Map` implementation as well to do the lookups correctly.